# html code in Response.Write

Tags: html, asp-classic

Hie, i need to include a html code in Response.Write. My code goes like this

```
Response.Write "<table><tr><td><label style=""width: 61px""><font size=""2"">Candidate:&nbsp; </font></label></td>
                <td>
                <input name="pcfname" value="<%=session("Fname")%>"  maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:79%"/>
                <label style="width: 41px">First</label></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td>
                <input name="pclname" value="<%=session("Lname")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:39%"/>
                <label>Last</label></td></tr></table>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                <label><font size="2">Classification:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pclassif" value="<%=session("classification")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:13%"/><br /><br />
                <label><font size="2">Degree Sought:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pdsought" value="<%=session("degree_sought")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:16%"/><br /><br />
                <label><font size="2">Completion Date:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pdsought" value="<%=session("completion_date")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:16%"/><br /><br />"
```

it shows me the error "Unterminated string constant" , am unable to figure out.

Some suggestions will be of great help.

-thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes to encapsulate your HTML so the double quotes in the HTML don't terminate the string.

```
Response.Write '<table><tr><td><label style=""width: 61px""><font size=""2"">Candidate:&nbsp; </font></label></td>
                <td>
                <input name="pcfname" value="<%=session("Fname")%>"  maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:79%"/>
                <label style="width: 41px">First</label></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td>
                <input name="pclname" value="<%=session("Lname")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:39%"/>
                <label>Last</label></td></tr></table>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                <label><font size="2">Classification:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pclassif" value="<%=session("classification")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:13%"/><br /><br />
                <label><font size="2">Degree Sought:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pdsought" value="<%=session("degree_sought")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:16%"/><br /><br />
                <label><font size="2">Completion Date:&nbsp; </font></label>
                <input name="pdsought" value="<%=session("completion_date")%>" class="" maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:16%"/><br /><br />'
```

Comment: Also: Using the FONT tag and using TABLES for layouts went out of use 10 years ago. I sure hope you're maintaining old code and not building something new.

Comment: In addition, a better way to display those 5 or so fields is using a panel control, which you show / hide based on need.

Comment: Thank you.It shows my "td" "table" tags are mismatched, though they are correctly closed. Do i need to do anything with them?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best if I correct one line and you can work the rest out

```
<input name="pcfname" value="<%=session("Fname")%>"  maxlength="255" size="14" style="width:79%"/>
```

should be rewritten as

```
 response.write "<input name=""pcfname"" value="""&session("Fname")&"""  maxlength=""255"" size=""14"" style=""width:79%""/>" &vbcrlf
```

Note

1. Double double quotes for html attributes
2. <%=objectname%> is a small asp scriptlet, so you can't put it inside another scriptlet. concatenate the object name with ampersands instead

I'm not sure why you'd even want to do all that in a response.write statement. Why not just close your asp scriptlet, write it as html then open a new scriptlet